# Is there a way to use javascript and the node module (oracledb) to import a csv to an oracle database?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, oracle

I am currently trying to use the node module Oracledb to import a csv to my database.  The database is connected correctly, as I can SELECT * FROM MYDB.  But I cannot find a way to easily import a CSV to this database.

*note : I am currently using jsontoCSV and then fswrite to create the CSV.  So if it is easier to write a SQL query to import a json to Oracle using Oracledb, that could also work.

Thank you.

Comment: if you're using Oracle REST Data Services and if you've REST enabled a table, you can simply POST a csv up and we'll batch insert the records for you https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e56293/develop.htm#BABCACEC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User SQL*Loader as mentioned.

- create table

  `drop table mytab;
  create table mytab (id number, data varchar2(40));`
- mycsv.csv

  `"ab", "first row"
  "cd", "secondrow"`
- Create control file myctl.ctl:

  `LOAD DATA
  INFILE 'mycsv.csv'
  INSERT INTO TABLE mytab
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  TRAILING NULLCOLS (id, data)`
- Run:

  `sqlldr cj/cj@localhost/orcl control=myctl.ctl`

Answer (score 1):

I only have a rough management overview on oracle techniques. I would guess to use sqlloader or datapump (abbrevated dp) to read csv; perhaps using additionally (oracle) external tables (could be accessed via file system). It depends on your infrastructure.

The internet is full of examples. One main ressource for me is "ask tom" (use your fav. search engine with the words oracle ask tom kyte).